# How to store a "primary key" in Local Storage JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this html code to take values from a user:

`<input type="text" id="orderName" name="orderName">`

Then I am storing it in a variable:

`var orderName= document.getElementById("orderName").value;`

Then I am storing it in local storage like:

`localStorage.setItem("orderName",orderName);`

Right now I can only store ONE orderName. I want to store MANY like it works in an SQL table or a MS Access table. Then use that primary key value to pass and persist to bring up data related to that primary key ONLY for example price, tracking number etc only related to that value.

Basically how do I make local storage work like a normal table?

Comment: store an array in the localStorage, for example. You will have to stringify the array (to json, for example) because localStorage or (sessionStorage) only accept strings

Comment: local storage is not a database. If you want to store multiple, use json.stringify

Comment: you can use an [IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/indexeddb) for such use-case or as other mentioned, keep an array and save the stringified array to the localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can store all the value to an array and access it
```

```
<input type="text" id="type" name="type">

<input type="text" id="price" name="price">

<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity">

var orderName= document.getElementById("orderName").value;

var type= document.getElementById("type").value;

var price= document.getElementById("price").value;

var quantity= document.getElementById("quantity").value;

var a = [];

a.push(orderName, type, price,quantity);

localStorage.setItem("inputValues",a);
```

Comment: Thank you but the user will be inputting values everytime the user presses submit an array should form dynamically. How do I do that?

Comment: I did something like this so that instead of a hardcoded "inputValues"  I can match the data to the orderName and us it like a key.

  var a[];
  a.push(orderName, type, price,quantity;
  localstorage("${orderName}",a);

 But its not working